# python, list compare, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Here is my python code:

```
def ava_check(nodes_group,child_list):
    ava_list=nodes_group[:]

    if nodes_group[1] in child_list:
        return None
    else:
        for a in nodes_group:
            if a in child_list:
                ava_list.remove(a)
                ava_list.remove(nodes_group[nodes_group.index(a)-1])
            else:
                pass
```

The `nodes_group` is a list like `[0.0, (0, 3), 0.0, (0, 2), 0.0, (1, 3)]`.
The `child_list` is a list like `[(0, 1)]`.

But when I run the code, there is an error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` happened in line `if a in child_list:`. I have no idea what is the problem here. I tried to search, but they said something about numpy. But I didn't use numpy here, the two inout arguments are just list with tuples.

Could you help me with this problem?

Thanks very much.

UPDATE: Thanks for everyone's solution. Some data (not tuples) in the list nodes_group are from the `numpy` array. But I store the data in new list. So I checked the data type of the element in the new list using type(), and I found that the type is `numpy.float64`, which explains why I have this error. So I write a loop to change the type of element in list from `numpy.float64` to int by just using `int()`. So the problem is solved. But anyone know whether is a better solution or more pythonic way? Thanks.

Comment: The above code can be run on repl.it without bugs. This is another thing I don't understand.

Comment: There is no `if a in nodes_group` in your code. Please update with the correct line.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Thanks. I changed the typo already.

Comment: @Eg_Tan Are you *sure* you aren't using `numpy` arrays?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not in this function. The float data (not tuples) of the list nodes_group comes from the numpy array, but I store them in the list.

Answer (score 1):

One (or more) of the values in your `nodes_group` list is a `numpy` array, not a float or tuple like you show in your example data. You can't use the test `a in some_list` if `a` is an array, because an array's `==` operator doesn't return a `bool` value, but rather a Boolean array. The Boolean array raises the exception you see when Python tries to covert it to a single `bool`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it now. But there is no array in nodes_group. The three '0.0' are from the array A, but I store them in the list nodes_group. The array A is like `A=np.zeros((10,10))`. Does it mean all the three '0.0' are not float but array?